# What is typically included in the OnStart or a Xamarin.forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application uses a database and the connection is currently created with this code when the DataAccess is first referenced:

```
    public static DataAccess DataAccess
    {
        get
        {
            if (dataAccess == null)
            {
                dataAccess = new DataAccess();
            }
            return dataAccess;
        }
    }
```

Would it be more appropriate to put this on the OnStart? I'm just not sure as the current developer did it in the way above.

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }
```

Comment: I think the way you have it works just fine. Personally I use `OnStart` to handle authentication checks and also to check to see if the user finished the registration process and, if not, send them back to the page that they left off on.

Comment: The developer did it as singletone which is fine. It will create an object first time when app needs it and then reuse it.